# Alignment problem for a matrix

Tags: matrices, arrays

I have written the following matrix on Latex:

[image]

However, I would like the different elements to be aligned vertically, i.e.:

[image]

I have been unable to accomplish this. My code is the following:

```
\[\phi_1(\mathbf{x}) = 
    \left(
    \begin{array}{l}
        x_1^2
        \\
        \sqrt{2}x_1x_2
        \\
        x_2^2
        \end{array}
   \right)\]
```

Do you know how could I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`l` columns are left-aligned, while `c` columns are center aligned, so just change `l` to `c` in the array specification. That said, I'd rather use `pmatrix` from `amsmath` here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\phi_1(\mathbf{x}) = 
    \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
        x_1^2
        \\
        \sqrt{2}x_1x_2
        \\
        x_2^2
        \end{array}
   \right)
\]
With \texttt{pmatrix}:
\[
\phi_1(\mathbf{x}) = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1^2
        \\
        \sqrt{2}x_1x_2
        \\
        x_2^2
        \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well thank you then, I should have thought about it...